What are the possible colors for $q \bar{q} \rightarrow q \bar{q}$ via a virtual gluon?
I am confused because in "Introduction to Elementary Particle" from Griffiths, we have this vertex which makes sense to me. An up quark with color blue turns into an up quark of color red and the emitted gluon carries away the difference (time flows upward):

But what happens, when we look at the process $q \bar{q} \rightarrow q \bar{q}$ (time flows to the right):

Which colors are possible here? I think the upper left quark has to be green, and the upper right anti-quark has to be anti-red (because confinement). But what is the color of the gluon then?

Note that a 3x3 matrix representation of the SU(3) gluons includes at least one entirely diagonal basis.  I think this is most commonly $\lambda_8$, but you can choose your favorite basis.

Thanks for the advice, but I am a beginner in particle physics and looking for a more simple answer like which colors are possible.

The simple thing to do is track colors. We have:
$$ \bar G x \rightarrow \bar y z \rightarrow
w R $$
where upper (lower) case are (un)known colors, or anti-colors if there is a bar over the top.
Let check each possibility for $X$ and converse color at each vertex:
Red, $x=R$:
$$ \bar G R \rightarrow \bar G R \rightarrow
\bar G R $$
Blue, $x=B$:
$$ \bar G B \rightarrow \bar G B \rightarrow
w R $$
o.k, nothing works here.
Finally, we'll try Green:
$$ \bar G G \rightarrow \bar y z \rightarrow
\bar R R $$
Looking at page 252 of https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout8_2009.pdf we see
gluon states:
$$ g_1 = r\bar g $$
$$ g_2 = r\bar g $$
$$ g_3 = g\bar g $$
$$ g_4 = g\bar g $$
$$ g_5 = b\bar g $$
$$ g_6 = b\bar g $$
$$ g_7 = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(r\bar r - g\bar g) $$
$$ g_8 =  \frac 1 {\sqrt 6}(r\bar r + g\bar g -2b\bar b) $$
and a singlet:
$$ g_0 =  \frac 1 {\sqrt 3}(r\bar r + g\bar g +b\bar b) $$
The singlet state is ruled out by confinement, while $g_7$ couples to both sides. I am not sure how $g_8$ fits in--it's been a while. But:
Red for sure, and I'm pretty sure green works. On page 267 Thomas shows how to sum over colors with the Gell-Mann matrices, but that is not beginner particle physics.
Note, though, that the gluon basis is arbitrary. I'll explain what that means by analogy.
Suppose you have a spin-0 two fermion state going through an intermediate state to a spin-0 two fermion state. We'd write that state in the $z-$basis:
$$ \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow
\downarrow\rangle -
 |\downarrow
\uparrow\rangle )$$
and talk about the spins of intermediate states w.r.t to $z$.
That is just for doing math in $SU(2)$. Nature doesn't know how we chose the z-axis, and it can physically point in any direction--since the initial and final states are scalars, they don't care about direction, let alone our definition of it.
The same is true for color in $SU(3)$. We pick $rgb$ directions and work through amplitudes, but irl, the physics doesn't depend on it. Actual quarks are in an entangled state of all colors such that our choice doesn't matter.
Tl;dr: don't think calling a quark "red" means it actually has color-charge red irl.

thanks for the detailed answer! So the gluon is in a superposition. So for the diagram $r\bar{r}$ or $g\bar{g}$ would be the correct colors for the gluon or can you not really say it like that?
